# factor columns read from csv to data.table or data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I tried to use `data.table` for `csv`-file with factor columns and faced with inexplicable behavior. The following is sample code:

```
> df <- read.csv('avgpm25.csv', colClasses = c('numeric', 'character', 'factor', 'numeric', 'numeric'))
> dt <- fread('avgpm25.csv', colClasses = c('numeric', 'character', 'factor', 'numeric', 'numeric'))

> summary(dt$region)
   Length     Class      Mode 
      576 character character 
> summary(df$region)
east west 
 442  134
```

So, it can be seen the `data.table` cannot read factor column, but dataframe can. What is the reason of this behavior and what is the right way to process factor columns with `data.table`?

***UPDATE:*** 
There is the list of columns

```
> colnames(df)
[1] "pm25"      "fips"      "region"    "longitude" "latitude"
```

When I tried `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` I have got character column "fips" became factor too. Meanwhile dataframe keeps original types.

```
> dt2 <- fread('avgpm25.csv', colClasses = c('numeric', 'character', 'factor', 'numeric', 'numeric'), stringsAsFactors = T)

> summary(dt)
      pm25            fips              region            longitude          latitude    
 <skipped>        Length:576         Length:576           <skipped>  
                  Class :character   Class :character   
                  Mode  :character   Mode  :character     

> summary(dt2)
      pm25             fips      region      longitude          latitude    
<skipped>         01003  :  1   east:442     <skipped>
                  01027  :  1   west:134   
                  01033  :  1              
                  01049  :  1              
                  01055  :  1              
                  01069  :  1              
                  (Other):570                                               
> summary(df)
      pm25            fips            region      longitude          latitude    
 <skipped>        Length:576         east:442     <skipped>
                  Class :character   west:134     
                  Mode  :character
```

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. Or just convert the relevant columns after `fread()`, since that function is optimized. `dt[, x := as.factor(x)]`

Comment: @RichScriven `as.factor` is still slow when there are many levels, using `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` will use internal faster version of as.factor.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Then convert some cols to character afterwards?

Comment: @RichScriven - Thank you. I added some info to question